# RecorderJS doesn't work anymore

Tags: google-chrome, web-audio-api, recorder.js

I try to use RecorderJS with this callback in `getUserMedia`. One month ago this code worked, but now I have some trouble about this. When `onaudioprocess` in `recorder.js` are executed the array buffer contain only 0.

I use this code callback for use `Recorder` object.

```
function gotStream(stream) {
    inputPoint = audioContext.createGain();

    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    realAudioInput = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    audioInput = realAudioInput;
    audioInput.connect(inputPoint);

    recorder = new Recorder(inputPoint);
}
```

I think something has been changed with Chrome. Anyone have some suggestions to give me?

Comment: You don't state what platform you're on, and version - and do you have a live pointer to the demo?

Answer (score 0):

It's `createGainNode`, not `createGain`.

Comment: Actually, it's createGain() now - the spec has been updated - but Chrome currently supports both.

Comment: Wow. They're changing this API all over the place. createJavaScriptNode, noteGrainOn, createGainNode... But they're all getting shorter, so I can't complain.